# Can't find package that's in the repository

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I am trying to install `crafty` in Debian Jessie but no installation candidate is available.

My `etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

After `apt-get update`.
Output of `apt-cache search crafty`:

```
dreamchess - 3D chess game
eboard - GTK+ chessboard program
eboard-extras-pack1 - additional piece sets and sounds for eboard (pack 1)
crafty-bitmaps - bitmap images for crafty chess game annotation mode
crafty-books-medium - Medium size opening books for the crafty chess engine
crafty-books-medtosmall - Medium-to-small size opening books for crafty chess engine
crafty-books-small - Small-size opening books for crafty chess engine
```

Comment: That search only shows add-on packages for `crafty`, not the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

[Crafty](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/crafty) : You will have to add the repository `non-free`.

(Synaptic → Settings → Repositories ...........)

Or add `non-free` component to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/games/crafty) `crafty` in Jessie is contained in the [non-free](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#s-non-free) repository. Take a look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Component) for more on the non-free and its URLs.